# Rails validation: How do you properly validate an invalid non-numeric input on a numeric field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

ActiveRecord apparently will recognize if a non-numeric input is given for a numeric field such as integer or decimal. In these cases, the value is converted to 0 (or 0.0 if a decimal field). Since this occurs before validation, a regex validation meant to detect non-numeric characters such as given below will not work.

`validates :fee, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d{0,11}(\.?\d{0,2})?\z/ }`

If a value 'a' is given, it will be saved to the database as 0 and no validation errors will be returned. Although this may be acceptable in many cases, it would be ideal to detect the invalid input and return the validation error to the user.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen any documentation on this so here's the answer I found:

Use `numericality: true`

This will return a validation error for a non-numeric input on a numeric field.

`validates :fee, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d{0,11}(\.?\d{0,2})?\z/ }, numericality: true`

The regex validator will still properly validate any numeric inputs.